# Is there a time limit in Super Mario Maker?

Tags: super-mario-maker

I was playing this game on Wii-U yesterday at a retail store, but each time I was only allotted 10 minutes.  Is this a feature of the game itself or is this a feature of the demo game?

What I mean by 10 minutes, is I started the game and in the top left corner it said 10 minutes, then began counting down.  Once the 10 minute timer expired the game automatically restarted.  I assume it is a feature of the demo only mode, not an actual restriction on designer mode.

I have never heard of a game putting a time limit, but wanted to check before I purchased the game and was disappointed.

Comment: 10 minutes as in the game closed after 10 minutes?

Comment: @indeed - yes when I started the game it said 10 minutes in the top left corner and the game would reset once the timer expired.

Comment: This is probably a mechanic built into the store display WiiU to prevent someone from spending a very long time playing with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a feature of the game itself. I have played in sessions that exceeded 10 minutes by significant values of time. If I had to speculate, this was probably a demo restriction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no time limit in creating a level, if that is what you mean. There is a time limit on finishing the level, something that you can set yourself (if you make the level), everywhere between 10 and 500 seconds.

Comment: Last I checked, the level timer only goes up to 500 seconds.

Comment: [Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805618-super-mario-maker/72067485) is goes to 999. Will change it anyhow, because someone agrees with you :)

Comment: @Mathias711 Not sure what they were using to change it.  Got the game on launch day and it has never let you increase the time past 500 seconds.

Comment: @Powerlord Most likely, they were misremembering, or simply wrong, possibly just guessing without actually having tried it.

Answer (score -3):

there is no time limit in the real bought game, you can play for as long as you want in 1 session